# Cannot get spring bean?

Tags: spring

Can't get bean from spring container in listener or filter classes.

Comment: Show us how you do it in filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used something like this :

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

ICustomer customer = (ICustomer) context.getBean("name"); // here name is the name of the bean you want to get context
```

look I  have used this in my project like this ans works well :

```
String processorName = Introspector.decapitalize(command.getClass().getSimpleName() + "Processor");
ICommandProcessor processor = (ICommandProcessor) context.getBean(processorName);
```

here if I ll pass `command` `Add` then it ll pass `processorName = AddProcessor` and get it's context.

what is your requirement ? can you post code ?

Look this xml file then check yours from it :

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">            
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="txManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

here : `<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain"/>` is important when you want to use `@Autowired` in my project it's `com.domain`, so refer this and make changes as you need. then again post.

Comment: but I can only get bean names those defined in spring xml,can not get the autowired beans...

Comment: Have you made interface of that and implement them in class ?

Comment: all interfaces are implemented.

Comment: Ok now working perfectly ? what changes have you made ?

Comment: **I wonder if the annotation injection is different from xml manual injection?**
Annotation scan type will only init manual defined beans in spring xml when tomcat start;
If you config you beans in spring xml,then all beans will be init on server startup.
Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, try it using log4j, it will show all information. when you will see console or log file then you will get that what all process done by tomcat, I also don't know but few months ago I have used log4j then I understand all process.

Comment: Nice idea,I'll try it later and tell you when it runs normally.THX

Comment: @kop_still - ok keep smiling.. :)